# how to remove a class when value evaluates to nothing using ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a class called `.lines-hover` that I want to remove once the values in the `td` are empty.

Here is an example of what I want: http://www.eag.ag/core/newengine/wager/sports.php?msg=true

Look at the lines, on some of those, let's say, Money Line is empty, then the `.lines-hover` becomes **false**. I want to do it with ng-class, but I am just starting with Angular and I did not understand the examples on their Docs.

**HTML:**

```
<td class="lines-hover">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" >
  <span ng-hide="row.noTotal">
   {{:: row.total.type}}{{:: row.total.spread}}({{:: row.total.moneyLine}})
  </span>
 </a>
</td>
```

**CSS:**

```
.lines-hover:hover {
  background: #3B3F45;
  a {
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngClass` like this, since `row.noTotal` is truthy when there are data:

```
<td ng-class="{'lines-hover': !row.noTotal}">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <span ng-hide="row.noTotal">
            {{:: row.total.type}}{{:: row.total.spread}}({{:: row.total.moneyLine}})
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
```